# Sending serial port data from QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

`I've tried for a few hours now to send a simple message to my Rasberry Pico through COM12 but I can't get it to work.

I'm fairly certain my Pico is set up correctly because when I use Hercules to send data it pick up the data just fine, it's just that I have to set the Mode from "Free" to "Data". on Hercules.  Not sure what that means.

Am I sending the data wrongly formatted or what's wrong?

I do get "Data sent successfully" but the Pico is still not receiving  it. I do however get the error "QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread" even though I'm not using timers nor threads.

```
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QSerialPort serialPort;

    serialPort.setPortName("COM12");
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serialPort.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serialPort.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (serialPort.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QByteArray input = QString("addPoints").toLocal8Bit();
        qint64 bytesWritten = serialPort.write(input);

        serialPort.write("test");

        if (bytesWritten == -1)
        {
            qDebug() << "Failed to write to serial port:" << serialPort.errorString();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Data sent successfully";
        }

        serialPort.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried changing the data type that is being sent, .toLocal8Bit(); was one thing I tried.`

Comment: Could you please share all of your code if possible and OS/QT version?

Comment: @LadyBeGood i don't know if its bugged but after i literally gave up I was frustrated i just spammed run and it worked... apparently when i open the port with putty , then closed putty and ran the code it worked. So i had a similar code, and everytime i opened the port with putty first it works.

Comment: Sounds weird, I used QSerialPort with different boards stm32 series, rasberry pico, arduion etc didn't encounter with such a problem. If you are using QT6, you may take a look at bug tracker.